# WPF popup closes when using Windows' on-screen keyboard

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

Whenever I try to use the on-screen keyboard to type text in a TextBox inside a popup within a WPF window, the popup is closed.

The behaviour can be reproduces easily using the following code.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Popup.StaysOpen = false;

        Open.Click += (e, sender) =>
        {
            Popup.IsOpen = true;
            Text.Focus();
        };

        Close.Click += (e, sender) =>
        {
            Popup.IsOpen = false;
            Open.Focus();
        };
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Button x:Name="Open"  Padding="16 9" Background="#FFFF00">Open</Button>
            <Popup x:Name="Popup">
                <Border Background="#FF00FF" Padding="16 9">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBox x:Name="Text"  Width="300" Margin="0 0 0 9" Padding="16 9" />
                        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" x:Name="Close" Padding="16 9" Background="#00FFFF">Close</Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </Popup>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Is it somehow possible to prevent Windows' on-screen keyboard from closing the popup without setting `Popup.StaysOpen = true`?

Comment: It's the default behavior. Another thing to do is to bind the IsOpen property and set it to false when required.